# How can I push only the last commit to the newly added empty repository?

Tags: git, github, heroku, push, commit

I have git a `origin` repository with 85 commits. I have also in this project Heroku remote repository and the third newly added `test` empty repository. I would like to push to the `test` repository my latest commit. I try it using `git push test 77feq3231bc0fd432233214af3e224ds397397:master` however I get:

```
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:myuser/test.git'
```

Any ideas how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot push a commit without also pushing all of the history *behind* the commit, leading up to the commit, that the other end doesn't have.

That said, where you are going wrong is a simple syntax issue.  You just need to write:

```
git push test <hash>:refs/heads/master
```

#### Why this is so

Consider:

```
git push $remote $hash:master
```

(where `$remote` is a remote name like `test`, or a raw URL, and `$hash` is a commit hash ID).  Your Git knows only that there is an object ID, `$hash`, that it should send to the other Git.  It should then ask the other Git to set a reference name to that hash ID.  The reference name you gave is `master`—but is that `refs/heads/master`, a *branch* name?  Or is it `refs/tags/master`, a *tag* name?  Or is it some other name entirely?

Your Git also looks at all *their* Git's refs.  But the `test` repository is empty and has no refs, so your Git does not find `refs/heads/master` there, and hence can't use that as the full name.

Normally your Git would then figure this out from the *left* side of the `:`, e.g., `git push test xyzzy:master` would have your Git look up the name `xyzzy`.  That would be a branch name—`refs/heads/xyzzy`—or maybe a tag name, `refs/tags/xyzzy`.  That would tell *your* Git: "ah, don't just ask the other Git to set `master`, ask it to set `refs/heads/master` or `refs/tags/master` depending on `xyzzy`".

Comment: So if it is impossible to push only one commit the solution seems to be removing git and create it one more time with initial commit. Then all needed files will be in this commit so it will be possible to push only the latest one to the new added GitHub repository?

Comment: You could make a commit whose history is just the one commit. This is what happens when you make a new commit on a branch made with `git checkout --orphan`. The new commit made after that is a root commit, so its history is just itself.

Comment: Okay, but let's assume that I have already a branch master with three commits in my github repository. Can you show me how can I push only the latest one commit?

Comment: Make a *new* commit with no history. First, set up the index so that it has the contents you want in the new commit. (To do this, check out the contents you want, which might mean "check out the tip commit of master", which might be where you already are. The point of this instruction is to *make sure* that the index matches the contents you want for the new commit.) Then, run `git checkout --orphan newbranch`, and then run `git commit` to create the new branch. You now have a branch whose entire history is a single commit: the commit you just made. Pushing that branch to [continued]

Comment: ... Pushing that branch to any repository anywhere will, if successful anyway, create a one-commit branch within that repository.

Comment: So I have to create just a new branch a then push it to this GitHub repository?

Comment: Specifically, a new *commit* that has no *parent*. To do so, create a branch that has no commits and thus does not exist, using `git checkout --orphan`, then make a new commit, which creates the branch. The new commit you create—which is a *new* commit, it is not any existing commit—has no parent, and is the only commit on the new branch just created. Pushing this branch pushes this commit *with all of its history*, but since that is *no* history, you get what you wanted.

Comment: I tried what you described: 1.`git checkout --orphan master2` 2.`git add -A`3.`git commit -m "Initial commit"`4.`git push test ds23...ds:master` but I get the same error as I had `error: unable to push to unqualified destination: master ...`

Comment: You're still trying to push by hash ID. If you do that you *must* spell out the reference. You can use the new branch's name instead: `git push test master2:master`, for instance.

Comment: When I push using `git push test master2:master` to the empty GitHub repository everything works fine, however when I have in my GitHub repository for instance 3 commits and I want to push this one from my master2 branch I still get `hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do...`

Comment: A branch name, in Git, points to *one single commit*. If you were to push this new commit-with-no-history to your GitHub `master` branch, your GitHub repository would have no name for all the other commits that used to be reached by starting from the commit to which the name `master` pointed and working backwards from each commit to its parent. That's why I pointed out, way back at the beginning of all of this, that pushing one commit necessarily includes all the history behind that one commit: the *name* `master` can only record one commit; it's that one commit that records more.

Comment: @SkybuckFlying: that requires making a new root commit. You can do that with Git (start with `git checkout --orphan` or `git switch --orphan`, populate the index as desired if necessary using whatever Git tools you like, then `git commit` to make the new root commit) but it's not packaged up into a convenient user-facing command.